# Trying to delete specific row in a list of items from a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of items that is being output via PHP / MySQL. I also have an Edit button and a Delete button in one column. I am trying to figure out how to delete a list item on a specific row by clicking the Delete button. I have tried the following:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_POST["deletelist"])) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM lists";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

    $query = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE id = '$id'";
} else {
        echo "Cannot delete";
    }
}
```

This of course does not work. Can anyone help me out with this?

**UPDATE**

This is the code for the entire page:

https://pastebin.com/raw/qjnZkUU2

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_POST["deletelist"])) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM lists";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

    $query = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
} else {
        echo "Cannot delete";
    }
}
```

What I am confused about is how does the query know which item to delete? Should I be appending the ID to the URL to pass the ID?

**UPDATE**

Ok I think I get it....In the delete button, I need to echo the ID of that row so when the query runs from clicking the delete button, it knows which ID to delete correct?

**RESOLVED**

Alright. I got it figured out!

I have a button that references the ID of the list item:

```
echo "<a href='includes/deletelist.php?id=$row[id]'><input class=\"btn btn-danger\" value=Delete style=\"width: 85px;\"></a>
```

I then pass that ID to deletelist.php

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'No ID was given...';
    exit;
}

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') ' . $con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE id = ?";
if (!$result = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    die('Query failed: (' . $db->errno . ') ' . $db->error);
}
```

Item gets deleted.

Comment: show the HTML code please

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: You never execute the delete query

Answer (score 4):

you have to execute query for any action in database

```
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

so execute a delete query and then try it again

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute the query. There is no query execution code. Try this

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_POST["deletelist"])) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM lists";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

    $query = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
} else {
        echo "Cannot delete";
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I be getting undefined index for I'd?

Comment: Be careful using user input from GET directly in a statement! Better use prepared statements with param binding. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1915746

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a specific row what I needed to do was echo the ID within a link/button. This would then pass the ID to the needed PHP to delete the row from the database.

**Echoing the row ID in the button**

```
echo "<a href='includes/deletelist.php?id=$row[id]'><input class=\"btn btn-danger\" value=Delete style=\"width: 85px;\"></a>
```

**The PHP to delete the action row**

```
<?php

include("db.php");

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'No ID was given...';
    exit;
}
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') ' . $con->connect_error);
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE id = ?";
if (!$result = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    die('Query failed: (' . $db->errno . ') ' . $db->error);
}

if (!$result->bind_param('i', $_GET['id'])) {
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}
if (!$result->execute()) {
    die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}
if ($result->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo "The ID was deleted with success.";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't delete the ID."; }
$result->close();
$db->close();
header('Location: ../account.php');
?>
```

This deletes the item row and then returns the user to account.php. Which in this case, the page never really changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try like below

```
if(isset($_POST["deletelist"]) && isset($_GET['id']) ) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lists";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

         $query = "DELETE FROM lists WHERE id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$id)."'";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
    } else {
        echo "Cannot delete";
    }
}
```

Comment: *try like below* is not an answer. Explain what you have changed and why

Comment: @Jens  mysqli_real_escape_string need to use for remove the mysql ejection . 

and mysqli_query($db , $query)  need to execute for any mysql action.

Thanks

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` does not prevent SQL injection completly.

Comment: This function add an escape character, the backslash, \, before certainly  dangerous characters in a string passed in to this function. SO we can prevent this issue by using this function.

Comment: read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391315/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-enough-to-avoid-sql-injection-or-other-sql-attack